# в Plotly на графике по оси y значения находятся в рандомном порядке

Tags: python, plotly

Проблема в plotly, есть значения даты и цены, но график строится хаотично по цене вместо того чтобы строить в порядке возрастания по цене.[image: Результат]

[image: Входные данные]

```
def plot_raw_data():
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['Date'],y=data['Open'], name="stock_open"))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data['Date'], y=data['Close'], name="stock_close"))
fig.update_layout(showlegend= True,title='Time Series data with Rangeslider')
st.plotly_chart(fig.show)
```

Comment: Не похоже на проблему с plotly. судя по скриншоту у вас что-то не то с данными. в таблице есть данные каждого дня только на 6 утра. а на графике у вас распределения по часам за сутки. Либо скриншот не отражает в полной мере данные либо еще что-то. посему, добавьте в вопрос пример исходных данных, пожалуйста.

Comment: @strawdog при использовании go.Candlestick и указание date. open. high. low и close данных график строится исправно, но при использовании go.Scatter и указание x=date y=open(close). то получается по оси y рандомное расположение цены  вместо упорядоченного.